# MySQL Having clause with a Correlated query is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a problem in my having clause. I want to compare between two sum having the same Bid but different sens fields 
I get this output:

```
SELECT v.bid 
FROM   v1 v 
WHERE  sens = 'c' 
GROUP  BY bid 
HAVING Sum(mont) < (SELECT Sum(l.mont) 
                    FROM   v1 l 
                    WHERE  sens = 'd' 
                           AND l.bid = v.bid group by l.bid);
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Field 'v.bid unknown in field list`

Edit : V1 is a view, i used aliases l and v trying to ling the sub query to the main query

Sorry guys thank you all for your answers, i was having an issue wuth the columns of the original table and now it is solved :)

Comment: Post the script of `V1` !! -> `CREATE VIEW v1 AS...` ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for two selects from this table, you can use `CASE EXPRESSION` for this purpose :

```
SELECT v.bid FROM v1 v
GROUP BY v.bid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN v.sens = 'c' THEN v.mont ELSE 0 END) <
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.sens = 'd' THEN v.mont ELSE 0 END) 
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN v.sens = 'c' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen :S Do you have a column `bid` in table `v1` ? @Bili

Comment: @Bili Unlikely, unless you have no bid field in v1 table.

Comment: it's a view not a table, and yeah it have a column bid

Comment: @Bili Then please post the View DDL .

Comment: i want to get bid having the sum(mont) of 'c'  < sum(mont) of 'd' , there are lots of rows having the same bid and the same sens  , i sum rows having the ssame 'd' and the same 'c' both having the same bid

Comment: Yes I understand what you want, but this query should be perfectly fine and shouldn't through an error. Are you sure same error occurs? Edit the question and add the view DDL .

Comment: mysql> SELECT v.bid FROM v1 v
    -> GROUP BY v.bid
    -> HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN v.sens = 'c' THEN v.mont ELSE 0 END) <
    ->        SUM(CASE WHEN v.sens = 'd' THEN v.mont ELSE 0 END)
    ->    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN v.sens = 'c' THEN 1 END) > 0;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Champ 'v.bid' inconnu dans field list
mysql>

Comment: Not the query you're running, the SCRIPT that creates the VIEW `v1` @b

Answer (score 3):

The alias in subselect is not visible/available so you get and column not found error but you can refactor your queru this way

```
  select  v.bid, t.tot 
      from v1 v 
    Join (
       select  bid, sum(mont)  tot
        from v1  
        where sens = 'd' 
        group by bid
        ) t on t.bid = v.bid
    where v.sens = 'c' 
    and v.bid < tot
```

Comment: the alias is not visible yes, but isn't a more direct way to write this query ???

Comment: @Bili  . sorry there is an error in alias .. i have update the query ..

Comment: @Bill  for me this kind of query  (using aggregated function in join are a powerful way for filter and select mixed value(aggregate and not aggregate)  select from  different tables

Comment: `mysql>  select  v.bid, t.tot
    ->       from v1 v
    ->     Join (
    ->        select  id, sum(mont)  tot
    ->         from v1
    ->         where sens = 'd'
    ->         group by id
    ->         ) t on t.id = v.id
    ->     where v.sens = 'c'
    ->     and v.bid < tot;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Champ 'id' inconnu dans field list`
mysql>

Comment: @Bili   .  i'm sorry mismatch id with bid  .. answer updated

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with the visibility of the columns because the view was improperly declared , i apologies guys :'( i feel really bad :(

the script:

```
mysql> select * from op;
+------+------+------+------+
| bid  | cid  | sens | mont |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | c    | 2000 |
|    1 |    1 | c    | 2000 |
|    1 |    1 | c    | 2000 |
|    1 |    1 | c    | 2000 |
|    1 |    2 | c    | 2000 |
|    1 |    3 | c    | 2000 |
|    2 |    3 | c    | 2000 |
|    1 |    1 | d    | 2000 |
|    2 |    3 | d    | 4000 |
+------+------+------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)


create view v1 as ( select bid , cid , sens , sum(mont) as sumcli from op group by bid,cid,sens);

mysql> select * from v1 ;
+------+------+------+--------+
| bid  | cid  | sens | sumcli |
+------+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    1 | c    |   8000 |
|    1 |    1 | d    |   2000 |
|    1 |    2 | c    |   2000 |
|    1 |    3 | c    |   2000 |
|    2 |    3 | c    |   2000 |
|    2 |    3 | d    |   4000 |
+------+------+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT v.bid
    -> FROM   v1 v
    -> WHERE  sens = 'c'
    -> group by v.bid
    -> HAVING Sum(v.sumcli) < (SELECT Sum(l.sumcli)
    ->                     FROM   v1 l
    ->                     WHERE  sens = 'd'
    ->                            AND l.bid = v.bid group by l.bid);
+------+
| bid  |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Rather than replying with the details, you should edit your question to put the view declaration there as it is necessary to reproduce the error you get. Then, in your answer, you can actually point out the issue and how to solve (but not introduce new details, those belong in the question).